# Xamarin.Forms Images Localization

Tags: image, localization, uwp, xamarin.forms

i'm creating Xamarin.Forms Application for Android and UWP and i use RESX files to switch between Languages (English as default and Arabic) and it's working fine.

the language switch is in the runtime on demand from Button Click event,
the path for the images in UWP is `Assets/Images/en` and `Assets/Images/ar` the images set is the same in both folders with the same names but the loaded images always from `Assets/Images/en`.

the RESX files names Resources.ar.resx and Resources.resx

i load the images with single method in a static class in PCL and used in PCL

```
public static ImageSource GetImageSource(string imageName)
        {
            return Device.OnPlatform(
                                     iOS: ImageSource.FromFile("Images/" + imageName),
                                     Android: ImageSource.FromFile(imageName),
                                     WinPhone: ImageSource.FromFile("Assets/Images/" + imageName));
        }
```

and i use this method when i detect language change from  `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.
my problem is when i change the language the strings of controls is working fine but the images doesn't change and always from `Assets/Images/en`.

I followed the localization and image work from this 2 links in Xamarin Guide

[Localization](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/)

[Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)

if there's a working sample that do localization in runtime and handling images it would be great.

Comment: I'm just curious: Why (and how) do you change the platform on a button click? I can't see a useful situation for this

Comment: @DennisSchröer For Why : it's Client requirement. For How : as i said i followed the 2 links in my question